# WebStorm debugger not able to start server?

Tags: debugging, webstorm

Whenever I run a Node.js application in WebStorm using debugger, the Node.js server doesn't start. But whenever I click on just the "Run" button, it starts.

Can someone help ?

**Run Config:-**
[image]
**Console:-**
[image]
**Debugger Console:-**
[image]

Comment: what happens namely? does it exit with some error code, or just 'hang'? What run configuration do you use to start it? What IDE version do you use?

Comment: It just hangs. When I say hang, I mean that it shows me the run command that it tries to execute and that it tries to listen on the inspect port but the server doesn't get up. I don't think it is a configuration issue, since normal run button works fine for me. 
I am using WebStorm 2020.1.1 Build #WS-201.7223.93

Comment: does your server spawn child processes? Please share a screenshot of your run configuration + screenshot of the debugger console

Comment: Not sure about the child processes. Guide me on how to check that?
PFA the screenshots in the original post.

Comment: you have to inspect your server code to check this - i'm not aware of any other way to do this:)

Comment: I am surviving on running the server with --inspect  and watching it manually through the debugger given in webstorm. I think, i'll just change webstorm to a version I last remember worked.